# Amazon S3 move a folder to a different path via aws CLI - even it just contains sub-folders only

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have some data in a bucket on S3 aws. I have to move it to a new folder in same bucket. Folder contains sub-folders and some times files also. I am using `aws CLI` utility for this purpose. Unfortunately, It is not going to move a sub-folder and work for files only. I have browsed it documentation from [this source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/mv.html), but not successful.

```
aws s3 mv "$S3_ROOT/src/" "$S3_ROOT/old/" --recursive
```

In above command, src contains a sub-folder that should be copied. In my case, as already said, sometimes sub-directory will be empty.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you require an empty folder? For example, is it causing a program to fail?

Answer (score 3):

Folders do not actually exist in Amazon S3.

For example, you could upload a file to `invoices/January.txt` and the `invoices` folder will 'magically' appear. Then, if the object is deleted, the folder will magically disappear (because it never existed).

One exception to this is when a user clicks the **Create folder** button in the S3 Management Console. Clicking the button will create a **zero-length object with the same name as the folder**. This will force the folder to appear because there is an object in that path (even though that object is not shown).

In your case, it would appear that the `mv` command is not copying those zero-length objects.

In general, it is best to ignore folders in S3 and just pretend that they exist in the places that you want them to exist, rather than 'creating' an empty folder.